# Can someone explain --> private BrowserWindow mParentWindow { get; set; }

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Can someone explains me below piece of code? basically what it is, what its doing, and why do I need mParentWindow? Cannot I do it with just ParentWindow

```
private BrowserWindow mParentWindow { get; set; }
public BrowserWindow ParentWindow { 
   get {
      if (this.mParentWindow == null) {
        this.mParentWindow = TopParentWindow();
      }
      return this.mParentWindow;
   }
}
```

Comment: what needs explaining.. are you serious you don't understand the code you posted..? here is a great place to start learning [C# Basics Tutorial - Properties](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_properties.htm)

Comment: Do you understand what a [Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) is? What do you think is happening here? It's great that you're coming to c# with a problem to solve, but it would be best to run through a basic c# tutorial before resorting to a question.

Comment: *Lazy Initialization* - It ensures that however many times you read `.ParentWindow` the process that retrieves it (`TopParentWindow()`) is only called once, the first time its needed.

Comment: I just confused why I need another property "mParentWindow" to simply get BrowserWindow. I thought I should be done like this
`code`
public BrowserWindow ParentWindow { 
   get {
      if (this.ParentWindow == null) {
        this.ParentWindow = TopParentWindow();
      }
      return this.ParentWindow;
   }
}

Comment: mParentWindow isn't a property, it's a field. Follow the links.

Comment: In your example you call `this.ParentWindow = TopParentWindow()` but there is no setter, you need something to store the value ...

Comment: ah... right, yeah link seems very useful. It good start to learn Property in C#.

Comment: thanks everyone.. I think I first need to read out about Property in details.

Comment: Also reading a property in its getter will fire its getter ad infinitum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you could set `mParentWindow` to `public` and remove the `m`.This code you've provided creates a read only property inside a class. You've added a `private BrowserWindow` which can be altered at your will from within the class it belongs to but not accessed or altered outside it. Then you have the read only property that can be accessed but not altered from outside its parent class.
I'll try to explain this better below:

```
private BrowserWindow mParentWindow { get; set; }
```

This line creates an instance of the `BrowserWindow` class that can be accessed and altered because of the presence of the `get` functions but only inside the parent class because it is `private`.

```
public BrowserWindow ParentWindow
{ 
    get
    {
        if (this.mParentWindow == null)
        {
            this.mParentWindow = TopParentWindow();
        }
        return this.mParentWindow;
    } 
}
```

This code creates an instance of the `BrowserWindow` class that can be accessed but not altered because there is a `get` function but not a `set` function. This can be accessed outside the class because it is `public`.
     Inside the `get` function the code says that if the value of `mParentWindow` has not been previously set, set it to the result of the `TopParentWindow` function.
     After this it returns the value of `mParentWindow`.

Comment: Property in example should be made public to match description. Also the main deal with the OP's posted code is the Lazy Initialization, which isn't mentioned here. The first paragraph is good to plainly describe the property (minus lazy), however, so good writing.

Comment: I accidentally hit enter before I'd finished.

Comment: thanks guys and @Rariolu ... I am good now. It answers what I was looking for.